Porque los jobs no se ejecutan cuando hago mi test
les doy rápido mi contexto.
Estoy usando Laravel 10 con php 8.2, y estoy realizando algunas pruebas, pero al realizar el post donde de hace el dispose del Job, este no entra a la función del handler.
Pero este si funciona en producción.
Ya ejecuté el comando:
php artisan queue:work

Ya Tambien en el phpunit.xml, le coloque en la opción de <server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="database"/>  y si realiza la inspersion en la base de datos de prueba, pero no el borrado. Lo que si hace es cuando yo ejecuto directamente el job en el test. Pero no en la aplicación.
Si alguien sabe que es lo que esta pasando me podría ayudar.

Que tipo de test estás haciendo? Si es un unitario, con verificar que se hace el dispatch del job es suficiente, luego testeas el job. Esto sería correcto porque no testeas la infraestructura, ya debe estar testeada en los vendor denlaravel.

Estoy haciendo los feature, el problema es que cuando realizar el Job este realiza otra acción en la base de datos que se usa en otro controlador

Usa php artisan queue:failed y luego revisa los logs a ver si hay algun problema.

@Excorpion ya ejecuté el comando y no sale ningún error actual, todos son anteriores, bueno anteriores a que me dieran el proyecto

Esto hay que apañarlo de forma general, no se trata de el debug de un codigo si no de el debug en general de los jobs ... te deje una respuesta un tanto integral ...

Hay muchas cosas que pueden estar pasando...
veamos como te puedo ayudar a resolver el problema, no soy un experto pero le meto a laravel de ves en cuando...
Verificaciones iniciales:

Verifica tu configuración de QUEUE_CONNECTION: Asegúrate de que en el entorno de pruebas, la conexión para las colas sea consistente. Confirma que QUEUE_CONNECTION=database está configurado correctamente tanto en el archivo .env.testing como en phpunit.xml.
Confirma el funcionamiento de las colas en pruebas:

Comprueba que la cola está procesando los Jobs.
Usa el siguiente comando para simular el procesamiento:



php artisan queue:work --queue=default --env=testing


Asegúrate de usar el Trait InteractsWithQueue: En tu Job, utiliza el Trait Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue para asegurarte de que Laravel maneje correctamente el ciclo de vida del Job.

Ahora veamos una posible solucion paso a paso "basado en mi entorno de desarrollo":

Revisa el handler del Job
El método handle en tu Job debe estar correctamente configurado y ser ejecutable. Por ejemplo:

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class DisposeJob
{
    use Queueable, InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct(public $data) {}

    public function handle()
    {
        // Lógica para manejar el Job
        \Log::info("Job ejecutado con éxito: ", ['data' => $this->data]);
    }

    public function failed(\Throwable $exception)
    {
        \Log::error("Job falló: ", ['exception' => $exception->getMessage()]);
    }
}

Nota: de esta forma lo tengo yo y no me ha dado problema hasta el momento...

Configura tu ambiente de prueba:

hechale un ojo al archivo .env.testing y si tiene la configuración adecuada para la conexión de la base de datos y las colas:
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_DATABASE=:memory:


Configura el PHPUnit para pruebas de Jobs

En el File phpunit.xml debería incluir la configuración:
<server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="database"/>
<server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
<server name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>


Asegúrate de procesar los Jobs en pruebas:

En tus tests, puedes usar el siguiente patrón para procesar los Jobs inmediatamente, esto me ha ayudado avismalmente los ultimos 6 meses:
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue;

public function test_job_dispose()
{
    Queue::fake();

    // Despachar el Job
    $job = new DisposeJob(['key' => 'value']);
    $job->dispatch();

    // Verificar que el Job fue despachado
    Queue::assertPushed(DisposeJob::class);

    // Procesar el Job inmediatamente
    Queue::assertNothingPushed(); // Confirma que no queda pendiente
}


Otra curiosidad que tambien me gusta es procesamiento síncrono en pruebas.

en el entorno de pruebas, puedes configurar el QUEUE_CONNECTION para usar el driver sync en lugar de database. Esto ejecutará los Jobs inmediatamente:
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync

Solución para el problema del borrado en base de datos
Si los Jobs no se están eliminando de la base de datos después de ser procesados, verifica lo siguiente:

Configuración del worker: El comando queue:work debería ejecutarse con la opción --tries para evitar que los Jobs queden pendientes en caso de errores:

php artisan queue:work --tries=3


Errores en el Job: Asegúrate de que el Job no esté fallando silenciosamente. Los errores pueden detener el proceso de borrado.

Middleware para el manejo de fallos: Agrega un middleware que registre los fallos:


use Illuminate\Queue\Middleware\RateLimited;

public function middleware()
{
    return [new RateLimited('default')];
}

Recomendaciones adicional:

Revisa siempre los log de PHP y Laravel.
Verifica manualmente la tabla jobs para observar qué Jobs están pendientes.

Esta es una solución integral, con estas adecuaciones y pasos deberias de conseguir el culpable y poder solucionar el problema y cualquier situación a futuro, ya que no se trata de un error en un código específico.
Cualquier duda tenemos un canel de php ....
